# How do I call my functions correctly in python?

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

I have been having trouble with my `def main()` section, specifically when I call to loop through the other variables.

I checked to see if my parameters check, which they do.  When I comment the section out, the code "works" in that and it doesn't crash. When uncommented though, it keeps saying my `fileInput` variable is referenced before the assignment.

I then tried switching my `fileIn` in `def readFile()` to before my if `yearIn` == 2008, but now the error is showing an expected string value (I didn't "" my years as I want it to be an integer).

What exactly is it I am doing wrong?  I want my code to run and output a file that lists out the cars with the highest and lowest MPG.

```
def readFile(yearIn):

    # open file
    if yearIn == 2008:
        fileInput = open("epaVehicleData2008.csv", "r")
    else:
        fileInput = open("epaVehicleData2009.csv", "r")

    fileIn = open(fileInput, "r")

    # open file
    # if yearIn == 2008:
    #     fileInput = open("epaVehicleData2008.csv", "r")
    # else:
    #     fileInput = open("epaVehicleData2009.csv", "r")

    count = 0

    #empty list
    manufactureList =[]
    carTypeList = []
    mpgList = []


    for line in fileIn:
        line = line.strip()
        carInfo = line.split(",")
        if count != 0:
            if "VAN" not in carInfo[0] and "PICKUP" not in carInfo[0] and "CLASS" not in carInfo[0]:
                manufactureList(carInfo[1])
                carTypeList(carInfo[2])
                mpgList.append(carInfo[9])
        count += 1

    maxMPG = max(mpgList)
    minMPG = min(mpgList)

    minCars = []
    maxCars = []

    for X in range(len(mpgList)):
        if mpgList[X] == minMPG:
            result = manufactureList[X] + " " + carTypeList[X]
            minMPG.append(result)

        if mpgList[X] == maxMPG:
            result = manufactureList[X] + " " + carTypeList[X]
            maxCars.append(result)

    #close
    fileIn.close()

    return maxMPG, minMPG, maxCar, minCar



def writeFile(fileName, year, maxMPG, minMPG, maxCar, minCar):

    #open file
    fileOut = open(fileName, "w")

    print("EPA Highway MPG Calculator", year, file = fileOut)
    print("-----------------------------------")
    print("Maximum Mileage (highway):", maxMPG, file=fileOut)
    print("\n".join(maxCars), file=fileOut)

    print("Minimum Mileage (highway):", minMPG, file=fileOut)
    print("\n".join(minCar), file=fileOut)

    #close file
    fileOut.close()


def main():

    print("Welcome to EPA Mileage Calculator.")

    #user select year
    yearIn = int(input("What year would you like to view data for (2008 or 2009)? "))

    #invalid input if neither 2008/2009
    while yearIn != 2008 and yearIn != 2009:
        print("Invalid input, please try again.")
        yearIn = int(input("What year would you like to view data for (2008 or 2009)? "))

    fileNameSave = input("Enter the filename to save results to (.txt file): ")
    print("Operation Success! Mileage data has been saved to", fileNameSave)
    print("Goodbye.")


    maxMPG, minMPG, maxCar, minCar = readFile(yearIn)

    #minMPG = readFile(yearIn)
    #carTypeList = readFile(yearIn)
    #manufactureList = readFile(yearIn)

    writeFile(fileNameSave, yearIn, maxMPG, minMPG, maxCar, minCar) 

main()
```

Comment: `fileIn = open(fileInput, "r")`... But `fileInput` is already an open file!

Comment: By the way, the traceback of the actual error would be useful here... or a [mcve]

Comment: You appear to try and open the file twice once in the if-else block and then again immediately after. That seems unnecessary and in fact causes the error, because `fileInput` will be an open file when you pass it to `open` but `open` expects a name, hence the error. Try commenting that line out and changing fileInput to fileIn in the if-else block.

Comment: @PaulPanzer tried your suggestion on commenting out the line and changing it to fileIn, but now the Traceback says: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable where I do manufactureList(carInfo[1])

Comment: That's further down, so it is progress ;-) Anyway, try replacing the parentheses with square brackets. As your computer is trying to tell you and as the name suggests `manufactureList` is a list. You reference its content using square brackets. Parentheses are for function calls.

Comment: @PaulPanzer now that you pointed it out, I realized I forgot to append manufactureList and carTypeList like I did for the mpgList.append(carInfo[9]).  With that fixed, I reran the code again and now its showing the TypeError: expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextI0Wrapper for my fileIn = open(fileIn, "r")

Comment: Isn't that the line we had commented out?